# Updating term_relationships with new categories from CSV

Tags: mysql, sql, database, wordpress

I am trying to update `term_relationships` with new categories established from a CSV, and am not too familiar with SQL.

I have already uploaded the CSV to the database and created a table called `ut_csv`, this table has several columns but the important ones are the `ID` and the `category`. The `ID` is the specific posts `ID` and the `category` already has the `term_taxonomy_id`.

I ran two scripts, the first being:

```
INSERT INTO wp_term_relationships
(object_id,term_taxonomy_id,term_order)
SELECT ID,category,0 FROM ut_csv
where post_type = 'post'
```

this **failed** with the error of **#1054 - Unkown column `post_type` in `where clause`**

So I ran the script, but dropped the `where post_type = 'post`, and this ran a success but when I checked the `wp_term_taxonomy` the 5 categories had no count.

Again I am unfamiliar with SQL so I may be doing something wrong or completely stupid. Any advice / help would be great.

Thanks

Comment: One step at a time.  What is ut_csv?

Comment: could you include the table definitions, along with a small sample of what's in ut_csv?

Comment: @DanBracuk is the CSV uploaded to the database and is now a table. There  are several wordpress related rows such as the URL, post_tag, author, etc.